# How to handle the express router method result in BackBone.js using ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone.js now i need to handle the express router method result in BackBone.js using ajax i know how to do it with jquery.But without using jquery how to do it with Backbone.I have learned about Backbone router,model,view and collection but still i'm not clear.

app.js

```
  var express=require('express');
  var app=express();
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.all('*',function(req,res){

      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
      res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
      res.end();
   });
   app.listen(8080);
```

I'm handling all request in express depending upon the request i need to send the header and body of the page.In that 'result' parameter i'm sending the body and header but i don't know how to get that result in Backbone.js.Below code is to handle the ajax response from node js.Is it correct.

client.js

```
  var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
  var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/index.html',
    model: MyModel
});
 var coll = new MyCollection();

 coll.fetch({
     error: function (collection, response) {
        console.log('error', response);
    },
    success: function (collection, response) {
        console.log('success', response);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Are you using the collections of backbone to download html code?

Comment: @Maxi Baez no i'm not using collections to download html code.In server for all request first i will serve common html template.Then depending upon the request i will get the body and header of the page and send that to client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of catching all the routes try something like

```
app.get('/models/',function(req,res){
    res.json({{id: 1, name: 'max'},{id: 2, name: 'bill'}});
});
```

this is a sample json object of models.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

This is an empty model

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/model/',
    model: model
});
```

A collection that uses our empty model.

```
var coll = new MyCollection(); 
coll.fetch({success: function () {
    console.log(coll);
}
});
```

Ignore the error, just focus on the success.

This should work for you. A great tutorial series I found when getting started was 
http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/

Hope this helps

Comment: i have tried this ..result are not coming in the success callback instead of that its displaying in the browser page.

Comment: then you are trying to access the /model/ route in the browser instead of through backbone. 

You need to enable express static with app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

and then create a folder named public. In it have an index.html and in a scripts tag enter the Backbone code. I really suggest you follow a tutorial as this is not really the best way to organize your code.

Comment: i have already created public folder with html and js files.In browser i'm getting that index.html page for other request but for /model/ i'm not getting the index.html page..

Comment: You should not get index.html for the model request. The idea is to have a REST API so that the server returns JSON to the client. The JSON is passed to backbone as a collection and then you decide what you want to do with the information (display it, manipulate it, etc)

Comment: can u write one small example with backbone route and node js express.

Comment: The one above should work for you. Just place the 3rd code box in a <script> tag inside index.html then use 'onload' to call it.